# when can we use simple past instead of present perfect?

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

here are some examples from a grammar book :

> you can use the present perfect for new information:
>
> 1. "I've decided to quit my job." "Really? Why?"
> 2. We've sold our car. Now we take the bus every day.
> 3. They're having a party next week, but they haven't invited me.
> 4. I'm looking for Amy. Have you seen her?
>
> you can also use the past in these examples:
>
> 1. I decided to quit my job

why just example 1 can be written in past form? and actually, by this fact it should not!

> Present Perfect. This tense describes something that happened in the past, but that is related to something in the present.

**in general** when we can use simple past instead of present perfect or vice versa?

Comment: The book says 'You can also use the past in _these_ examples', not that you can only use it in example 1. It assumes that you know how to convert the other three into simple past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where was this grammar book published? American English speakers tend to use either present perfect  **or simple past** when British English would only use present perfect: see [this article](https://www.simpleenglishvideos.com/the-present-perfect-tense-in-british-and-american-english/) for more information.

I (British English) would not use simple past unless the time it happened is stated in the sentence, or is clear from the context.

> 1. I quit my job **yesterday**
> 2. Q: So, what did you do about your problem at work?
>      A: I quit my job.

In example 1, the time is clearly stated. In 2, it's implied, because it happened as a consequence of the problem at work... the questioner knows when that happened.

If make a statement out of the blue, with no time and no context, I would use present perfect:

> I have quit my job

This [canonical post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it) explains very thoroughly when you would use present perfect.

Comment: yea, the book is American version, thanks a lot